# How can i convert a https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value response with Angular 9 to an image

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api, angular9

How can i convert a **https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value** response with **Angular9** to an image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W45jp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getProfileImg() {
this.http
  .get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photos/48x48/$value', {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'image/*' },
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
  })
  .toPromise()
  .then(
    (data) => {
      const TYPED_ARRAY = new Uint8Array(data);
      // converts the typed array to string of characters
      const STRING_CHAR = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, TYPED_ARRAY);

      //converts string of characters to base64String
      let base64String = btoa(STRING_CHAR);

      //sanitize the url that is passed as a value to image src attrtibute
      this.profileImg = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(
        'data:image/*;base64, ' + base64String
      );

      console.log(this.profileImg);
    },
     (err) => {
      this.profileImg = '../../assets/img/account_circle-black-48dp.svg';
    }
  );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

because the image returned is a binary representation of the image, you would need to convert it to read it. 
Here's an example of it for angular.

```
var imageUrl = 'data:image/*;base64,' + res.data;
```

This project is an example of how to use graph with angular which displays the users information. the link goes directly to the little section about the image conversion. 
https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Angular-Microsoft-Graph-Profile/blob/7ed7e89a03525fa79b9d6bed7fb17d257a4c9ff2/app/controllers/mainController.js#L120

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
as the user is already logged in, i Just used the getProfileImg() and was able to get the image from AD Profile.
I applied Css as per my image need and that worked.
Thank you!